# Search text by ASCII code in SQL Server for ASCII 63

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a special char in my table records (many of them)

It is this char ◾

When I try to search for records that contain this char I get all the records for some reason.

This is my query

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM X2 
where txt like N'%◾%'
```

I found ASCII = 63

I wonder if there is a way I can search in text with ASCII code?

I tried this but get no records

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM X2 
where txt like N'%' + char(63) + '%'
```

Any idea how to get that?

I am using SQL Server 2019 (v15)

Comment: 63 is actually the question mark `?`, which is often returned for any invalid character when you try to convert it to ascii.

Comment: I'm *assuming* by "SQL Server 15" you really mean SQL Server **2019** (version 15.x.x)

Comment: @marc_s yes I mean SQL 15.x.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of how SQL Server does a Unicode compare and in short can be resolved by changing the collation e.g.

```
declare @Test table (test nvarchar(max));

insert into @Test (test)
values (N'a◾b'), ('asd');

select *
from @Test
where Test like N'%◾%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI;
```

Returns:

```
test
a◾b
```

Modify the collation to suit e.g. CI (Case Insensitive) <-> (Case Sensitive), AI (Accent Insensitive) <-> AS (Accent Sensitive).

For a full description see [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171331/why-does-searching-for-like-n-match-any-unicode-character-and-n-match).